# Add translucent tint to transparent UITableViewCell when cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have set up a transparent `UITableViewCell` and I would like it to be shaded but still not opaque when selected. This is what I added to `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to try to produce the effect:

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
bgView.alpha = .3;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
```

However this results in the cell turning an opaque gray when the cell is selected. How can I have a semi transparent gray? It seems as though setting the alpha has no effect? Or is there something I can set in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView Cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to correct this problem? I tried adding this line to the function, but I still have opaque gray cells instead of a cell with the low alpha I am setting.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.alpha = .3
```

Comment: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.3]; should set the color and not transparency of the cell, if that's what you're after

Comment: @Mercurial this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

in combination with your custom backgroundView.

Comment: this takes away all selection effect regardless of whether I set the selectedBackgroundView before or after. I want a gray tint when the cell is selected and no tint when it's not selected.

Comment: maybe try overriding `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: return `NO` so the cell can be selected but does not get highlighted

Answer (score -1):

You should override `UITableViewCell` class and implement `setSelected` and `setHighlighted` methods there. There you should set the background to your color or the default one.

Alternatively, however much uglier, you can override `willDisplayCell...` method and set the color there.

Don't forget to set cell selection style to `.None`.

Comment: Quite weird to downvote without comment. But well, what do I know ;) Especially that this answer also contains @Cameron E answer (check last sentence).